# CSS to rearrange text in an email?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to edit an email. I have something like the below. Is there a way I can use CSS to rearrange the below to look like the output below?

```
<span id="one">One</span>
Hello friend
<span id="three">Three</span>
Hello friend 2
<span id="five">Five</span>
Hello friend 3
<span id="two">Two</span>
Hello friend 4
<span id="four">Four</span>
```

**OUTPUT**

One

Hello friend

Two

Hello friend 2

Three

Hello friend 3

Four

Hello friend 4

Five

Comment: You can use inline CSS for your emails.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique. Try classes instead. And what CSS have you tried?

Comment: I changed the id's to be unique

Comment: You can use `order` if you make your items use flex box https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/order/

Comment: You can't use CSS to modify text that is *not* in an element. If there's anyway you can get your "hello" text inside elements, then we're off to the races. Otherwise, I think this is impossible.

Comment: are you creating an email that needs to be sent by mail server with embedded styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **css** to control the rendering of your document to be something different than the document order. I'd use **flexbox** for that (**display: flex**).
However, it also relies upon a certain regular structure to your HTML, which is not what I'm seeing in the example. Not sure if you are in the position to modify that or not.

```css
.container {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}

.first {
   order: 1;
}

.second {
   order: 2;
}

.third {
   order: 3;
}

.forth {
   order: 4;
}

.fifth {
   order: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">
    <span>This is the first</span>
  </div>
  <div class="third">
    <span>This is the third</span>
  </div>
  <div class="fifth">
    <span>This is the fifth</span>
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <span>This is the second</span>
  </div>
  <div class="forth">
    <span>This is the forth</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is ignoring the "hello friend" text between the spans in the OP's example.

Comment: @JonB OP just has to put the text inside `div.{number}`

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.

This would require the use of CSS properties and/or HTML attributes that aren't supported in every email client. See the [campaign monitor list of supported CSS properties](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) for more detailed info.

Coding for email is not like coding web pages. You're effectively limited to using CSS properties and HTML attributes that are universally supported across major clients. Using things like flex box and other fancy CSS3 properties aren't always reliable in email.

Additionally, it's almost never a good practice to have your HTML document re-ordered by CSS (unless absolutely necessary). It can create serious usability problems.

Comment: Some notes here about using flexbox in email: 

https://litmus.com/community/discussions/1500-using-flexbox-in-an-email

Comment: Flex is not supported by major web mail servers.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know of, no.  There is no way to do this with CSS.

The problem is that CSS is meant to 'beautify' DOM structure, but not alter it.  It looks like you're building the DOM structure in a way where you can't predict the order of the elements coming in.

Comment: I suppose in theory you could hard-code each element as `position: absolute` and set a `top` value corresponding to where it should be vertically placed, but that is incredibly hacky.

Answer (score -2):

try adding this to your css

```
span{
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't change the order

Comment: i see. i didn't see that 5 in the middle. the block display will perform the line breaks for him. js could be used to sort.